# Unlink Odoo Journal Entries

Tags: python, odoo

I am inheriting the account.move module so that I can delete journal entries.
The problem is that when I override the original code, I get a maximum recursion depth error:
The original code looks like this:

```py
 def unlink(self):
        for move in self:
            if move.name != '/' and not self._context.get('force_delete'):
                raise UserError(_("You cannot delete an entry which has been posted once."))
            move.line_ids.unlink()
        return super(AccountMove, self).unlink()
```

while this is my extension

```py
 def unlink(self):
        for move in self:
            move.line_ids.unlink()
        return super(AccountMove, self).unlink()
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to let you know that there is OCA repo for such thing `account_move_force_removal` https://github.com/OCA/account-financial-tools

Comment: Copied code from above and that worked. Thank you @kerbrose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
 def unlink(self):
        for move in self:
            move.line_ids.unlink()
        return models.Model.unlink(self)
```

If you want to bypass the security check then you have to call the base model directly.

Comment: Thank you this works too. Also when you add models.Model.unlink(self), the models.Model part references the current models

Answer (score 1):

Odoo 14 version code solution by snippetbucket team. via RPC call as well same context internally pass to remove account.move related records

```
    move2 = odoo2.env['account.move']
    _moves = move2.search_read([  ('state', '=', 'cancel'), ], ['id'], limit=1000)
    print( len(_moves), "total moves" )
    move2.with_context({'force_delete': True}).unlink([ x['id'] for x in _moves ])
```

With .with_context({'force_delete': True}) context you can delete journal entries and as well invoices from ODOO 14.x version and future version as well.

Note: account.invoice replaced in odoo 14 version to account.move.